# Is there anything available for .NET to get the differences in two strings?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, string, diff

I'm looking for a way to determine the differences between two strings, and highlight them in both strings.

I would suspect that most 'diff' libraries won't work since they show differences in lines (I believe).

Either an algorithm or library will work.

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555531/any-existing-c-code-oss-that-will-calculate-diff-between-two-strings-and-outpu/1556086#1556086

Comment: @adrianbanks: The answer there doesn't do intra-line diffs which I think the poster wants.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008904/looking-for-method-to-tell-the-difference-between-to-strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/) can handle many different kinds of "intra-line" diffs, including character and word diffs.  I think it should be able to do everything you're asking for here.

Answer (score 2):

From your question, you seem to have rejected using an existing program and decided to write your own because you believe existing programs cannot show differences within lines.

However [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) can show intra-line diffs.

[image]

Does that meet your needs? Or do you need this to be a .NET component for some reason?

Comment: It's for integrating into an ASP.NET website, so needs to not be a program.  Clarafied question.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to look into using the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), or some [similar algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:String_similarity_measures) For a C# implementation of the Levenshtein algorithm, see [here](http://www.merriampark.com/ldcsharp.htm) (if you're really keen on writing this yourself).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1000635/c-show-the-differences-when-comparing-strings) asks something similar, with the accepted answer pointing to a bunch of [diff related projects](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?projectSearchText=diff). There's a lot of good code that's been written that's definitely worth taking a look into.

Answer (score 0):

String.Compare would work.  If you want to compare words then just split the initial string into an array of strings and loop through it.